# optimizing for loops in c++ code

Tags: c++, optimization

```
Integer Range = 1;
for(Integer k = -Range; k <= Range; ++k)
{
    for(Integer j = -Range; j <= Range; ++j)
    {
        for(Integer i = -Range; i <= Range; ++i)
        {
            Integer MCID = GetCellID(&CONSTANT_BOUNDINGBOX,CIDX +i, CIDY + j,CIDZ
                                     + k);
            if(MCID < 0 || MCID >= c_CellNum)
            {
                continue;
            }
            unsigned int TriangleNum = c_daCell[MCID].m_TriangleNum;
            for(unsigned int l = 0; l < TriangleNum; ++l)
            {
                TriangleID=c_daCell[MCID].m_TriangleID[l];
                if( TriangleID >= 0 && TriangleID < c_TriangleNum && TriangleID
                        != NearestID)// No need to calculate again for the same triangle
                {
                    CDistance Distance ;
                    Distance.Magnitude = CalcDistance(&c_daTriangles[TriangleID], &TargetPosition,
                                                      &Distance.Direction);
                    if(Distance.Magnitude < NearestDistance.Magnitude)
                    {
                        NearestDistance = Distance;
                        NearestID = TriangleID;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
c_daSTLDistance[ID] = NearestDistance;
c_daSTLID[ID] = NearestID;
```

**GetCellID is the function to return the cellid  in the variable CID with CIDX,CIDY,CIDZ with its position in the 3 axes**

here the above code is a function to calculate the distance ,actually STL distance between a point and the triangles of the stl. This code runs fine  however the problem is it is too slow as it has large number of loops within the code. Now my concern is to optimize the loop.  Is there any technique of optimizing the loops within the code?

Comment: Have you proven this to be "too slow" with a profiler? What timings are you looking at with what data? And what times are you looking for?

Comment: yes, this function takes almost 50% of total execution and initial target is to make it run faster than the present. no matter if it is a differnce of few second too.

Comment: what is your target hardware?

Comment: For starters: are you using maximum optimization?  Compilers are usually pretty good at optimizing this sort of thing.  Other than that, you don't show enough code to say.  What are the actual data structures involved?  Nor enough information from the profiler: how often do you enter the innermost loop?

Comment: Need to understand that to optimize: call of GetCellID or the inner loop. How the 50% is distributed between the call and the cycle?

Comment: What's the value of `Range`? If you are simply running MANY loops, perhaps you can store the objects such that you don't have to operate on so many items?

Comment: I would try to reduce the number of calls to this function through caching results. Is that possible? If you still need to optimize, please, show CalcDistance code.

Comment: I don't see how this is a CUDA programming question as written. I have taken the liberty of removing the CUDA tag. If/when you have a CUDA version of the code and have questions, ask a new question instead

Comment: @talonmies I have the above code as a kernel code actually . I am confused that if it is already inside cuda kernel section, can this if -else section can be optimized using kernel inside kernal??

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya: As I said, if you have a completely described CUDA example and profiling information or a concisely described problem with that example, feel free to ask a different, CUDA specific question.